# iOS app's archive data doesn't load properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, save, loading, archive

I'm pretty new to this, so bear with me.

I built an app using iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 4th ed called Homepwner which utilizes archiving to store information when the app goes into the background and load information when it starts up again, and it works totally fine. I decided to implement the same strategy for my own app called SBL, but when the app is loaded after having been quit, the data appears to load but doesn't display properly.

The app displays an array of "CCIEvent"s in a table and they appear like the example:

7:00 AM: Wet and Dirty Diaper

8:48 AM: Fed - Both - 20 min

9:48 AM: Napped - 1 hr 0 min

But when I quit the app and start it again, the list pulls up like this (I had to identify it as code to make this post, but the info below displays on screen in my table as such):

```
<CCIEvent: 0x154e44e20>
<CCIEvent: 0x154e2c7b0>
<CCIEvent: 0x154e77b90>
```

I really don't know where to look, but here's all the code relevant to saving/loading (I think):

In CCIEvent.m

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{

[aCoder encodeObject:self.startTime forKey:@"startTime"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.bedTime forKey:@"bedTime"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.wakeTime forKey:@"wakeTime"];
[aCoder encodeBool:self.isNap forKey:@"isNap"];
[aCoder encodeInt:self.feedDuration forKey:@"feedDuration"];
[aCoder encodeInt:self.sourceIndex forKey:@"sourceIndex"];
[aCoder encodeInt:self.diaperIndex forKey:@"diaperIndex"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.note forKey:@"note"];

}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{

self = [super init];

if (self) {
    _startTime = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"startTime"];
    _bedTime = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bedTime"];
    _wakeTime = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"wakeTime"];
    _isNap = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"isNap"];
    _feedDuration = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"feedDuration"];
    _sourceIndex = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"sourceIndex"];
    _diaperIndex = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"diaperIndex"];
    _note = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"note"];
}
return self;

}
```

In CCIEventStore.m

```
- (instancetype)initPrivate
{

self = [super init];

if (self) {

    NSString *path = [self eventArchivePath];
    _privateEvents = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

    // If the array hadn't been saved previously, create an empty one
    if (!_privateEvents) {
        _privateEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Did NOT load events");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Loaded events");
    }

}
return self;
}

- (CCIEvent *)createEventWithEventType:(NSString *)eventType
                         startTime:(NSDate *)startTime
                           bedTime:(NSDate *)bedTime
                          wakeTime:(NSDate *)wakeTime
                             isNap:(BOOL)isNap
                      feedDuration:(int)feedDuration
                       sourceIndex:(int)sourceIndex
                       diaperIndex:(int)diaperIndex
                              note:(NSString *)note
{

CCIEvent *event = [[CCIEvent alloc] initWithEventType:eventType
                                            startTime:startTime
                                              bedTime:bedTime
                                             wakeTime:wakeTime
                                                isNap:isNap
                                         feedDuration:feedDuration
                                          sourceIndex:sourceIndex
                                          diaperIndex:diaperIndex
                                                 note:note];
[self.privateEvents addObject:event];
return event;

}

- (NSString *)eventArchivePath
{

NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories firstObject];

return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"events.archive"];

}

- (BOOL)saveChanges
{

NSString *path = [self eventArchivePath];

return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.privateEvents
                                   toFile:path];

}
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {


BOOL success = [[CCIEventStore sharedStore] saveChanges];

if (success) {
    NSLog(@"Saved all of the CCIEvents");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Could not save any of the CCIEvents");
}

}
```

This is the some code from the view controller where the table is which I have called CCILogViewController.m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CCIEvent *event = self.sortedAndFilteredArray[indexPath.row];

    if ([event.eventType isEqualToString:@"sleepEvent"] && event.wakeTime) {

        NSDateComponents *dateComponentsToday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSInteger yearToday = [dateComponentsToday year];

        NSInteger dayOfYearToday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                           inUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                                          forDate:[NSDate date]];

        NSDateComponents *dateComponentsEvent = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                                                fromDate:event.startTime];
        NSInteger yearEvent = [dateComponentsEvent year];

        NSInteger dayOfYearEvent = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                           inUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                                          forDate:event.startTime];

        NSInteger dayOfYearWakeEvent;

        dayOfYearWakeEvent = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                     inUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                                    forDate:event.wakeTime];
        if (event.wakeTime && yearEvent == yearToday && dayOfYearEvent == dayOfYearToday - 1 && dayOfYearWakeEvent == dayOfYearToday) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:event.startTime], [self.sortedAndFilteredArray[indexPath.row] description]];
        } else if (event.wakeTime && yearEvent == yearToday - 1 && dayOfYearEvent == dayOfYearToday - 1 && dayOfYearEvent == 1 && dayOfYearWakeEvent == dayOfYearToday) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:event.startTime], [self.sortedAndFilteredArray[indexPath.row] description]];
        } else {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.sortedAndFilteredArray[indexPath.row] description];
        }

    } else if (self.dateOptionIndex == 2 || self.dateOptionIndex == 3) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:event.startTime], [self.sortedAndFilteredArray[indexPath.row] description]];
    } else {

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.sortedAndFilteredArray[indexPath.row] description];
    }

    if (event.note) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Here's how I get the sortedAndFilteredArray which is called in few different places including viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)sortAndFilterArray
{

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:self.arrayIsAscending];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [[[CCIEventStore sharedStore] allEvents] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    NSMutableArray *sortedAndFilteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (CCIEvent *event in sortedArray) {

        switch (self.eventOptionIndex) {
            case 1:
                if ([event.eventType isEqualToString:@"sleepEvent"]) {
                    [sortedAndFilteredArray addObject:event];
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if ([event.eventType isEqualToString:@"feedEvent"]) {
                    [sortedAndFilteredArray addObject:event];
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if ([event.eventType isEqualToString:@"diaperEvent"]) {
                    [sortedAndFilteredArray addObject:event];
                }
                break;
            default:
                [sortedAndFilteredArray addObject:event];
                break;

        }

    }

    NSDateComponents *dateComponentsToday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger yearToday = [dateComponentsToday year];

    NSInteger dayOfYearToday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                        inUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                                       forDate:[NSDate date]];

    for (CCIEvent *event in sortedAndFilteredArray) {

        NSDateComponents *dateComponentsEvent = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                                      fromDate:event.startTime];
        NSInteger yearEvent = [dateComponentsEvent year];

        NSInteger dayOfYearEvent = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                            inUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                                           forDate:event.startTime];

        NSInteger dayOfYearWakeEvent;

        switch (self.dateOptionIndex) {
            case 0:

                dayOfYearWakeEvent = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                             inUnit:NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                                            forDate:event.wakeTime];

                // Filter here for dateIndex 0 (Today)
                if ([event.eventType isEqualToString:@"sleepEvent"] && event.wakeTime && yearEvent == yearToday && dayOfYearEvent == dayOfYearToday - 1 && dayOfYearWakeEvent == dayOfYearToday) {
                    [finalArray addObject:event];
                } else if ([event.eventType isEqualToString:@"sleepEvent"] && event.wakeTime && yearEvent == yearToday - 1 && dayOfYearEvent == dayOfYearToday - 1 && dayOfYearEvent == 1 && dayOfYearWakeEvent == dayOfYearToday) {
                    [finalArray addObject:event];
                } else if (yearEvent == yearToday && dayOfYearEvent == dayOfYearToday) {
                    [finalArray addObject:event];
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                // Filter here for dateIndex 1 (Yesterday)
                if (yearEvent == yearToday && dayOfYearEvent == dayOfYearToday - 1) {
                    [finalArray addObject:event];
                } else if (yearEvent == yearToday - 1 && dayOfYearEvent == dayOfYearToday - 1 && dayOfYearEvent == 1) {
                    [finalArray addObject:event];
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                // Filter here for dateIndex 2 (Past Week)
                if (yearEvent == yearToday && dayOfYearEvent >= dayOfYearEvent - 6) {
                    [finalArray addObject:event];
                } else if (yearEvent == yearToday - 1 && dayOfYearEvent >= dayOfYearToday - 6 && dayOfYearEvent < 7) {
                    [finalArray addObject:event];
                }
                break;
            default:
                // No filter here for dateIndex 3 (All Time)
                [finalArray addObject:event];
                break;

        }

    }

    self.sortedAndFilteredArray = [finalArray copy];

}
```

This is what is being called when getting description of a CCIEvent:

```
- (NSString *)description
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    if ([self.eventType isEqualToString:@"sleepEvent"]) {

        NSString *bedTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.bedTime];
        NSString *wakeTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.wakeTime];

        long min = self.sleepDuration/60;
        long hrs = self.sleepDuration/60/60;
        long rMinutes = min - hrs * 60;

        if (!self.wakeTime && self.bedTime) {

            if (self.isNap) {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Went Down for Nap", bedTimeString];

            } else {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Went Down", bedTimeString];

            }

        } else if (self.wakeTime && !self.bedTime) {

            if (self.isNap) {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Woke from Nap", wakeTimeString];
            } else {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Woke", wakeTimeString];
            }

        } else if (self.sleepDuration <= 60) {

            if (self.isNap) {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Napped - 1 min", bedTimeString];
            } else {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Slept - 1 min", bedTimeString];
            }

        } else if (self.sleepDuration > 60 && self.sleepDuration < 60 * 60){

            if (self.isNap) {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Napped - %ld min", bedTimeString, min];
            } else {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Slept - %ld min", bedTimeString, min];
            }
        } else if (hrs == 1) {

            if (self.isNap) {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Napped - 1 hr %ld min", bedTimeString, rMinutes];
            } else {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Slept - 1 hr %ld min", bedTimeString, rMinutes];
            }
        } else {

            if (self.isNap) {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Napped - %ld hrs %ld min", bedTimeString, hrs, rMinutes];
            } else {
                return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Slept - %ld hrs %ld min", bedTimeString, hrs, rMinutes];
            }
        }

    } else if ([self.eventType isEqualToString:@"feedEvent"]) {

        NSString *startTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.startTime];
        NSArray *sourceArray = @[@"Both", @"Left", @"Right", @"Bottle"];
        NSString *sourceString = sourceArray[self.sourceIndex];

        return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: Fed - %@ - %d min", startTimeString, sourceString, self.feedDuration / 60];

    } else if ([self.eventType isEqualToString:@"diaperEvent"]) {

        NSString *startTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.startTime];
        NSArray *diaperArray = @[@"Wet and Dirty", @"Wet", @"Dirty"];
        NSString *diaperString = diaperArray[self.diaperIndex];

        return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: %@ Diaper", startTimeString, diaperString];
    }

    return [super description];

}
```

Comment: Can you post your method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Added. Thanks for giving this a look.

Comment: It looks like your tableView is always ending up setting this cell: `cell.textLabel.text = [self.sortedAndFilteredArray[indexPath.row] description];`

Comment: Yes, it's been a while since I started this project, but I believe that is correct. Do you think that will lead me to the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sprinkled my code with NSLogs and determined that my CCIEvents were loading just fine. I found it odd that my special description worked before loading but not after loading. Before loading it would give me the string I wanted, but after loading it would point to memory. After inspecting my description method, I noticed that I defaulted to returning the super's description method unless the CCIEvent met certain criteria, which forced me to realize that my CCIEvents have an attribute of eventType which I did not include in the encodeWithCoder: or initWithCoder: blocks. All I had to do was add eventType in there, and my description works like it should. Thanks so much, Chris! I literally left this project alone for months because I was so stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a custom description method in CCIEvent? By default, NSObject `description` will display the memory location of an object which is exactly what you're seeing. You can do a basic test by creating something very simple like:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", self.note];
}
```

It still seems like something isn't loading somewhere, or I'd expect you to see that problem during general usage. If you do have a CCIEvent `description` method, can you post it? I'm also curious about `sortedAndFilteredArray`.

You might try sprinkling your code with `NSLog()` calls to see if you're getting what you expect at various points. Keep an eye on the XCode console when the app runs to see what data you're getting. Ie, in CCIEvent.m `initWithCoder` you might add something like the following at the end of the `if (self) {` block:

```
NSLog(@"Got %@", _note);
```

Or even check your description method right there:

```
NSLog([self description]);
```

Also be sure to do some NSLog's in your `encodeWithCoder` method. My suspicion is the problem is occurring on the save side - there's something keeping event details from saving properly, so when they are restored they are empty so in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method it's hitting the default condition and just calling description on CCIEvent, which I suspect may not exist and is doing the default behavior of displaying the memory location. If I'm right, this points to a disconnect between CCIEventStore's privateEvents and the event being edited in your detail view. Check the object properties in your header files and see if somewhere CCIEvent is being passed around using copy rather than strong.

Unrelated to the error, but still worth noting - the item in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.sortedAndFilteredArray[indexPath.row] description];
```

Those lines probably aren't related to the issue, but they contain a redundant accessor. Since you already have:

```
CCIEvent *event = self.sortedAndFilteredArray[indexPath.row];
```

any times you want to access data from the event, you should use that variable, so the above textLabel would be:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [event description];
```

There are a few other places in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that could use a similar modification.

Hope this helps some!

Comment: Can't wait to get home and look into this. Thank you so much for even trying to help. I'll let you know if it leads to the solution.